Внедрение минимального числа в код, и вывод на 2 out
Хотелось бы ещё спросить, возможно ли в код внедрить, что бы минимальное число было для примера 1.00, и от него шел отсчёт? так же будет ли возможность вывести данный код сразу на 2 экрана, #out1, #out2, тобиш на 2 рядом стоящие панели одновременно, но при условии, что на одной с них(на #out2) не будет анимации(Перебегания от нуля до рандомного числа) а сразу число Random() спасибо за ответ!
const oneStepTime = 10;
    const disp = document.getElementById("out");
    const timerDisp = document.getElementById("timer");

    function randomFloat(maxNumber, maxStep, minStep) {
      let acc = 0;
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        let step = 0.01;
        if (maxNumber - acc > step) {
          acc += step;
        } else {
          acc = maxNumber;
          clearInterval(interval);
          run();
        }
        disp.innerText = acc.toFixed(2);
      }, oneStepTime);
      
    }

    function run(min, max) {
      const waitTime = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * 10000;
      console.log('Надо подождать', waitTime);

      let count = 10;
      const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timerDisp.innerText = count;
        count--;
        if (count < 0) {
          clearInterval(countdownInterval);
          timerDisp.innerText = '';
          randomFloat(Random(), 10, 1);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    function Random() {
      const max = 5;
      return Math.round(Math.random() * max * 100) / 100;
    }

  
    run(3, 10);


Так же есть баг с накладываниям чисел на одной плоскости, хотелось бы, что бы после выполнения randomFloat() число исчезало, а не накладывалось на run(), просле функции ран число снова появилось, и так до бесконечности, спасибо!

Про отсчет с 1 сделать можно. Про то, что бы один скрипт реализовывал разную логику отображения - наверное тоже можно.

Спасибо за ответ, немного подумал и сменил let acc = 0; на 1.00, пошло.
Только вовсе не понимаю как вывести числа на 2 разных дисплея и с исключением функции randomFloat()

Что бы отображать данные в 2-х и более разных тегах, надо эти теги создать и при запуске фукнции передавать значения во входящие параметры. Если убрать функцию randomFloat, то надо много чего переделать и понять логику, как это все должно работать.
